# Eventing in Ning

Tags: plugins, callback, hook, ning

I've been scouring API documentation but have yet to find something about this. I'm trying to get activity information from a Ning network as it happens. I want to know whenever any user comments, shares a photo, etc.

Is there any way to do this (ideally without having to poll for changes)? I can't find any references to eventing, callbacks, hooks, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ning API doesn't have a callback/event/hook API. Polling the [Activity endpoint](http://developer.ning.com/docs/ningapi/1.0/reference/activity.html) or one of the content specific endpoints is your only option.